# Prove Bernoulli's inequality for irrationals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have been working my way through a series of analytical proofs related to Bernoulli's inequality as follows:

1) Given $a>-1$ and  $a\neq0$ , show $(1+a)^n>1+na$ for any integer $n>1$

2) Given a sequence $\{x_n\}=(1+x/n)^n$, show that $\{x_n\}$ is monotone increasing for all $x>0$

3) If $a>0$, show that $(1+ar)^r>1+ar$ for any rational exponent $r>1$

I have completed these proofs without reference to the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality and without using a binomial power series expansion for the first term in each proof (I believe that was the intention of the questions at this point).

The final step in this series of proofs is to extend to the irrationals thereby proving that (3) hold for any real exponent $r>1$.

Any hints as to what may be a useful trick in a proof subject to the stated restrictions?

Comment: here you can find a proof http://planetmath.org/proofofbernoullisinequalityemployingthemeanvaluetheorem

Comment: It would have been nice to see the proof for an irrational number. Also, since every real can be expressed as a sequence of rationals, you could try using that approach